# Scroll bar not visible in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I have created a GUI in Java which looks as shown below -

'panel_mid' is the white panel in the middle. I have added it to a scrollpane called 'panel_mid_scrollpane'.

Apart from 'panel_mid' there are more panels -

- panel_left (containing 'back' button)
- panel_right (visible on right hand side)

[image]

Revelant code for this gui is -

```
    panel_mid.setBorder(grayborder);
    panel_mid.setBounds(0, 0, 1100, 1060);
    panel_mid.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel_mid.add(obj.create_test_add_section);

    panel_mid_scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panel_mid);
    panel_mid_scrollpane.setLocation(150, 20);
    panel_mid_scrollpane.setSize(1000, 660);
    panel_mid_scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

The **Add Section** button shown in panel_mid, adds a section to the middle panel, every time it is clicked. When this button is clicked multiple times, the gui looks like -

[image]

As you could see, the scrollbar does not appear automatically as panels are added, the last panel is thus only half visible. What could be causing this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrollbars appear automatically when the preferred size of the component added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

You appear to be using a null layout.

```
//panel_mid.setBounds(0, 0, 1100, 1060);
panel_mid.setBackground(Color.white);
panel_mid.add(obj.create_test_add_section);

panel_mid_scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panel_mid);
//panel_mid_scrollpane.setLocation(150, 20);
//panel_mid_scrollpane.setSize(1000, 660);
```

Don't use a null layout with setSize() and setLocation. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. If you use layout managers then the scrollbar will work automatically and the size and location will be calculated automatically for you.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Mangers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: But then how do i set width/height of panels ? The new elements when added now take up the whole space available, i want them to take fixed space everytime. Thanks

Comment: Use different layout managers to achieve you desired layout. I gave you a link to the tutorial that explains the basics. If you are creating a custom component and doing custom painting then you need to override the getPreferredSize() method to return an appropriate value. If you are just using existing Swing compnents then you don't need to do anything, Swing will determine the preferred size.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell the GUI to refresh, so that the containers are laid out again. This will show the container that it also has to show a scrollbar.

So in the ActionListener or whatever you use to add a section, add code like:

```
     container_with_sections.validate();
     container_with_sections.repaint();
```

where container_with_sections is the container (JContainer) which contains the JScrollPane, or a container which contains a container which contains the JScrollPane, and so on.

Comment: *«the container (JContainer) which contains the JScrollPane, or a container which contains a container which contains the JScrollPane»*, in other words, a parent of the `JScrollPane`.